# Porting a UDF from MS SQL Server to MySQL throws exception incorrect double value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have created a function on a MS SQL Server 2000 database that converts a base 10 number to base 64 and works fine for my purposes.  I also need this function to be in a MySQL database I have converted it however it throws an exception saying that

```
 Truncated double value 'B'
```

for example an example, now if I keep the number below 64 it converts it fine.
SQL function

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToBase64(@value int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @seq char(64)
DECLARE @result varchar(50)
DECLARE @digit char(1)

SET @seq = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@seq, (@value%64)+1, 1)

WHILE @value > 0
BEGIN
    SET @digit = SUBSTRING(@seq, ((@value/64)%64)+1, 1)

    SET @value = @value/64
    IF @value <> 0 SET @result = @digit + @result
END 

RETURN @result
END
GO
```

mySQL function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ToBase64( Pvalue int) RETURNS varchar(50)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE seq char(64);
DECLARE result varchar(50);
DECLARE digit char(1);

SET seq = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
SET result = SUBSTRING(seq, (Pvalue%64)+1, 1);

WHILE Pvalue > 0 do

    SET digit = SUBSTRING(seq, ((Pvalue/64)%64)+1, 1);
    SET Pvalue = Pvalue/64;

   IF Pvalue <> 0  THEN
        SET result = digit + result;
    END IF;

End While;

RETURN (result);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be your problem:

```
IF Pvalue <> 0  THEN
    SET result = digit + result;
END IF;
```

MySQL uses `CONCAT()` for string concatenation:

```
IF Pvalue <> 0  THEN
    SET result = CONCAT(digit, result);
END IF;
```

Comment: @jasemilly: In addition to the answer, be careful with `(@value / 64)` in SQL Server and `(Pvalue / 64)` in MySQL, the calculation results may be different.

Comment: yes, the results are different between mySQL and SQL